# Extracting events from Google Calendar

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

Today I created code:

```
// Create a CalenderService and authenticate
CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("j...@gmail.com", "mypassword");

// Send the request and print the response
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
CalendarFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(feedUrl, CalendarFeed.class);
System.out.println("Your calendars:");
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < resultFeed.getEntries().size(); i++) {
CalendarEntry entry = resultFeed.getEntries().get(i);
System.out.println("\t" + entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
}
```

This code gives out the list of all calendars. At me - a box calendar, a calendar of birthdays of friends and a calendar of holidays. I need to receive all events occurring today - i.e. both my notes, and birthdays of friends, and holidays. How I am able to do it?

This code returns event for specified data range, but it is work for private calendar only; i tried to replace "private" for "allcalendars", but it doesn't work:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

CalendarQuery myQuery = new CalendarQuery(feedUrl);
myQuery.setMinimumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2006-03-16T00:00:00"));
myQuery.setMaximumStartTime(DateTime.parseDateTime("2006-03-24T23:59:59"));

CalendarService myService = new CalendarService("exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
myService.setUserCredentials("jo@gmail.com", "mypassword");

// Send the request and receive the response:
CalendarEventFeed resultFeed = myService.query(myQuery, Feed.class);
```

Comment: Hi friend i want to start with app to integrate google calendar events in it. can u help me with some sample code or tutorial.

any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the your feed url. The one you are using is getting the events on the *default* calendar.

To get the other calendars you should replace *default* in the url by the calendar's id, for example:

```
feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com/private/full");
```